# JDBC and MySql install and configure

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I have to do a project using JDBC and MySql .. can someone guide me in this attempt to install and run these darn things? I can't figure out how and what to do. I have never worker with databases in my life, so i have no clue. What do i need to install, configure, etc? Can someone one offer some useful link for me to start with please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very nice tutorial created by Vogella: http://www.vogella.de/articles/MySQLJava/article.html

You will find there info how to connect your java program from downloading jdbc driver, creating database and executing simple commands through java.

Answer (score 2):

Install the database. Add the MySQL JDBC driver to your classpath. And follow the instructions of the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html).